# Acesso wcf via https

Tags: c#, web-service, wcf, services

Estou com o seguinte erro ao acessar uma url https:

```
O esquema de URI do provedor 'https' é inválido; esperado 'http'.\r\nNome do parâmetro: via
```

Meu arquivo a

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<configuration>
  <system.serviceModel>
    <client>
      <endpoint address="https://teste.com.br/Service1.svc" binding="wsHttpBinding" 
    bindingConfiguration="ServiceBinding1" contract="ServiceReference.ServiceContract"
    name="ServiceBinding" />
    </client>
    <bindings>
      <wsHttpBinding>
       <binding name="ServiceBinding1" maxReceivedMessageSize="2147483647">
         <reliableSession enabled="true" />
         <security mode="None" />    
       </binding>
      </wsHttpBinding>
    </bindings>
  </system.serviceModel>
  <startup> 
    <supportedRuntime version="v4.0" sku=".NETFramework,Version=v4.5.2" />
  </startup>
</configuration>
```

Tentei da seguinte forma também:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<configuration>
 <system.serviceModel>
  <behaviors>
   <serviceBehaviors>
    <behavior name="MyServiceBehavior">
      <serviceMetadata httpsGetEnabled="true"/>
    </behavior>
  </serviceBehaviors>
</behaviors>
<client>
   <endpoint address="https://teste.com.br/AgroMobileWCF/Service1.svc" binding="wsHttpBinding" 
    bindingConfiguration="ServiceBinding1" contract="ServiceReference.ServiceContract"
    name="ServiceBinding1" />
</client>
<bindings>
  <wsHttpBinding>
    <binding name="ServiceBinding1" maxReceivedMessageSize="2147483647">
      <reliableSession enabled="true" />
      <security mode="Transport">
        <transport clientCredentialType="None"/>
      </security>
    </binding>
  </wsHttpBinding>
</bindings>
</system.serviceModel>
<startup>
<supportedRuntime version="v4.0" sku=".NETFramework,Version=v4.5.2" />
</startup>
</configuration>
```

Obtive o seguinte erro:

```
Falha na validação de associação porque o WSHttpBinding não oferece suporte a sessões confiáveis em segurança de transporte (HTTPS). A fábrica de canais ou host de serviço não pôde ser aberto. Use a segurança de mensagem para proteger a troca de mensagens confiáveis em HTTP.
```

Código da requisão:

```
    public void Connect()
    {
        try
        {
            if (client != null)
                client.Disconnect();
        }
        catch { }
        try
        {
            ServiceReference.ServiceContractClient.CacheSetting = CacheSetting.AlwaysOn;
            client = new ServiceReference.ServiceContractClient();
            TimeSpan ts = new TimeSpan(0, 0, 0, 11);
            client.Endpoint.Binding.CloseTimeout = ts;
            client.Endpoint.Binding.OpenTimeout = ts;
            client.Endpoint.Binding.ReceiveTimeout = ts;
            client.Endpoint.Binding.SendTimeout = ts;

            client.Connect();

            var loginResult = (ServiceReference.LoginResult)client.SendLogin("CT", 1);

            if (!"OK".Equals(loginResult.STATUS))
                throw new Exception("Erro: " + loginResult.MENSAGEM);
        }
        catch (Exception ex) { return; }// throw ex; }
    }



[System.Diagnostics.DebuggerStepThroughAttribute()]
[System.CodeDom.Compiler.GeneratedCodeAttribute("System.ServiceModel", "4.0.0.0")]
public partial class ServiceContractClient : System.ServiceModel.ClientBase<LarWS.ServiceReference.ServiceContract>, LarWS.ServiceReference.ServiceContract {

 public LarWS.ServiceReference.Message Connect() {
        return base.Channel.Connect();
    }
 }
```

Comment: Dá uma olhada [nisso](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2435823/the-provided-uri-scheme-https-is-invalid-expected-http-parameter-name-via), mesmo problema ;)

Answer (score 0):

Modifique o seu `HttpBinding` para configurar o security mode para `Transport`

```
<bindings>
  <wsHttpBinding>
   <binding name="ServiceBinding1" maxReceivedMessageSize="2147483647">
     <reliableSession enabled="true" />         
     <security mode="Transport">
         <transport clientCredentialType="None"/>
     </security>   
   </binding>
  </wsHttpBinding>
</bindings>
```

E habilite o https no behaviour

```
<system.serviceModel>
    <behaviors>
        <serviceBehaviors>                
            <behavior name="MyServiceBehavior">
                <serviceMetadata httpsGetEnabled="true"/>
            </behavior>
        </serviceBehaviors>
    </behaviors>
    <!-- ... -->
</system.serviceModel>
```

Comment: Leandro, tentei fazer da forma que vc passou, obtive erro, conforme coloquei a pergunta. att

Comment: Na verdade o seu primeiro problema foi "resolvido", agora falta você alterar o seu código e fazer a autenticação para consumir o serviço. Inclua em sua pergunta o código da sua requisição.

Comment: Leandro, inclui o código onde faço a requisição.

Answer (score -3):

O erro "O esquema de URI do provedor 'https' é inválido; esperado 'http'." indica que você está tentando acessar uma URL com o esquema "https", mas o código espera que a URL tenha o esquema "http".

Para resolver o problema, você pode alterar a URL para usar o esquema "https" em vez de "http". Por exemplo, em vez de "http://teste.com.br/Service1.svc", use "https://teste.com.br/Service1.svc".

O segundo erro "Falha na validação de associação porque o WSHttpBinding não oferece suporte a sessões confiáveis em segurança de transporte (HTTPS)." indica que você está tentando usar sessões confiáveis (habilitadas com "reliableSession enabled='true'") com segurança de transporte (habilitada com "security mode='Transport'"). No entanto, o WSHttpBinding não oferece suporte a essa combinação de configurações.

Para resolver o problema, você pode alterar a configuração de segurança para "security mode='None'" ou "security mode='Message'", ou desabilitar as sessões confiáveis alterando "reliableSession enabled='true'" para "reliableSession enabled='false'".

Espero que isso ajude!